# Receiving broadcast in Windows 10 phone

Tags: windows, udp, broadcast, esp8266

I've got a Windows 10 based Mobile phone and want to receive a broadcast UDP packages send by a esp8266 breadboard. My mobile phone and esp8266 board are not connected to any wifi network or router so both have a fixed IP-addresses which can be completely different like: Mobile Phone => 10.0.0.1, esp8266 board => 192.168.1.1. The both have to communicate directly without a wifi-router.
Does somebody made this work or can tell me how get this working.

Regards, Wamor

Answer (score 0):

You could set the esp8266 up as an AP (access point). This allows you to connect to the esp8266 from your phone like you would to a wifi router.

Check out https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/example-sketch-ap-web-server for a tutorial on how to do this.

Another useful link to a project that is similar to yours:
https://www.hackster.io/rayburne/esp8266-access-point-using-arduino-ide-19f632

Comment: Hello L Bahr, thank you for your reply but I need to have this working the other way around. I future I could have multiple esp8266 modules which should communicate together trough my mobile phone. There for my phone should act as an AP and possible as a DHCP-server and router. Do you know if this is possible with Windows 10 Phone? Regards, Wamor

Comment: I can think of 3 things you can try: **1.** Have you tried to download a wi-fi hotspt app or adhoc network app. I don't have a windows phone, but you could try [this app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/wi-fi-hotspot-pro/9wzdncrfhv5v). **2.** If it doesn't have to be a windows phone, I know you can do this on android. **3.** If you have to use a windows phone and the app does not work you could set up a dedicated esp8266 to act as your AP. This may not be ideal, but it could work.

Comment: If my answer helped fix your issue, could you make it as the accepted answer @Wamor